# How do you make a symbolic link with a relative path using mklink?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, mklink

[This web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implies that it is possible to make symbolic links with relative paths using `mklink`.

I have tried all sorts of ways to make relative symbolic links, but I always end up with an absolute path.

How is it done?

Comment: MSDN has a strange way of explaining this. I had a hard time understanding how to make a symbolic link, since there are no actual examples.

Comment: The only reason I know this "strange way" is because MSDOS use this method.

Comment: I don't understand why my question has 20,000 views now, when the problem was caused by a bug in TCC/LE.  Symbolic links are made relative by default usually.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Symbolic links are relative by default. You have to explicitly write a drive letter to make any part of the link absolute.

The general syntax for a symbolic link is:

```
mklink link destination
```

So, to create a relative symbolic link: **`link`** is going to be a path relative to your **working directory**, and **`destination`** is going to be a path relative to **`link`**.

Examples:

```
1. mklink link.txt ..\destination.txt
```

This creates a symbolic link for `link.txt` which points to `destination.txt` one folder up.

You can move `link.txt` around, and it will always point to `destination.txt` one folder up.

```
2. C:\>mklink A\Link.txt ..\Destination.txt
```

This creates a symbolic link `C:\A\Link.txt` for `C:\Destination.txt`

Comment: This is it.  Rather than beginning with a drive letter or a backslash, you just begin with a directory. eg `mklink destination.txt "documentation\readme.txt"` will point to a child folder called *documetation" and a file in that folder called *readme.txt*.

Comment: @surfasb, @iglvzx: At first I was confused, as that is exactly what I have been trying.  But as you both confirm that this works, I have realised that it does work in `CMD`, but not in `TCC/LE`, which is what I have been using.  I am surprised that it is altering (expanding) path arguments for external programs.

Comment: @surfasb: This problem with TCC/LE has been fixed with the new v13, but happened with 12.11.76, which I had been using.

Comment: @paradroid: I'm glad it is working out. I remember fondly the old old version of TCC.  How long have you been using it now? On another not,  yeah, the nuances of PATH enumeration boggles my mind. And the obligatory [blog post]:(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/22/495740.aspx) about how past MS-DOS decisions towards compatibility **still** affects us today.

Answer (score 1):

To make relative link to a directory use `/D` switch

For example:

```
mklink /D lib\foo ..\foo
```

Links directory `foo` from parent directory as `lib\foo`.

When the link is moved to another directory, it will still point to `..\foo` in a relative sense.

Junctions created using `/J` switch can have relative path specified at the time of creation, however this path is resolved and junction will always point to an absolute path.

Comment: This is actually incorrect, as the `/J` switch is for making junctions, which are hardlinks, not symbolic links and has nothing to do with relative paths.

Comment: You are right - my bad. The `/J` switch makes the link absolute even when at the time of creation relative path was given.

Comment: Junctions aren't hardlinks, they're also a type of symbolic links (with slightly different semantics from "Unix symlinks" that `/d` creates), but it is true that they always use an absolute path. You can use `fsutil reparsePoint query` to see what path is stored inside a symlink or a junction. (Real hardlinks would not be reparse points at all.)