# Convert Linux symlinks to Windows symlinks

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cross-platform, symbolic-link

I've noticed that Linux symlinks don't work in Windows, and vice-versa. Is there any way to convert Linux symlinks to Windows symlinks? Specifically, I want to convert [relative Linux symlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/146231/how-do-i-create-arelative-symbolic-link-in-linux) to [relative Windows symlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/361826/how-do-you-make-a-symbolic-link-with-a-relative-path-using-mklink) (in case the folder with the symlinks is stored on a flash drive, or copied from a Linux filesystem to a Windows filesystem).

Comment: Basically, this question is asking whether it's possible to generate Mac and Windows symlinks on Linux, since creating cross-platform symlinks doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised - why did two people vote to close this question?

Comment: I wish I could move this question to unix.stackexchange.com, since it would be more relevant there. :/

Comment: There are some search results about converting Linux symlinks to Windows symlinks: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=convert+linux+symlink+to+windows&oq=convert+linux+symlink+to+windows&gs_l=hp.3..33i29.1313.6140.0.6240.32.32.0.0.0.0.220.3981.10j20j1.31.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.saNvCHzokTc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ&fp=df08fc36998c1ff1&bpcl=40096503&biw=1366&bih=631

Comment: @kojiro Would there be any way to migrate the question (along with the comments) there? I don't want to lose the comments that I've posted here.

Comment: I'm interested in this question but am a little unclear because these days I'm (mostly) a linux user.  I wasn't aware windows had symlinks. Are you referring to symlinks under cygwin or something else.  Thanks for your time and sorry for my ignorance on this.

Comment: More context please.  Are you talking about a dual-boot machine, or over the network, or removable disks, or something else?  Are you willing to write your own code or do you want an existing tool?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm willing to write my own code, definitely. I'm working with a dual-boot machine.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The file system is ext4. Would it be possible to create symlinks on Linux that would be portable from one ext4 filesystem to another?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm reading the ext4 filesystem from Linux, instead of Windows. It is the local filesystem, and I'm trying to create shortcuts for Windows on Linux, based on Linux symlink files. Is it possible to create portable Windows symlinks, by any chance? (I mean symlinks that would link to a relative file path, instead of an absolute file path).

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to create shortcuts, or symlinks?  If they're being created on an ext4 volume, which Windows can't read, what's the point?  Put another way, how are they going to eventually wind up being seen by Windows?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry for the typo: I meant "symlinks", not "shortcuts". Also, I would most likely copy the file from the Linux filesystem to Windows using Linux, instead of using Windows (since Linux can read both NTFS and ext4 filesystems, while Windows cannot.) The symlinks should be relative to the folder path, instead of absolute (if this is even possible - I really wish I'd done more research on this subject before posting this question).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6999/discussion-between-anderson-green-and-harry-johnston)

Answer (score -3):

Windows doesn't have symlinks per se. It has *shortcuts*, which are little more than special text files containing a destination location. They differ in features from symlinks. For example, this redirection on a POSIX system (including OS X):

```
./somecommand > ./somesymlink
```

will put the output of the command into whatever file the symlink points to, but on Windows

```
somecommand > someshortcut.lnk
```

would simply overwrite the shortcut – you'd end up with a text file with a confusing extension.

On the other hand, Windows shortcuts can contain commandline arguments that change the actual nature of the command. Symlinks don't have this capability (though with shell aliases, functions and scripts, you don't really miss it.)

That said, you can create a shortcut file [programmatically on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx), so you can create a script that will try to create the right file for your platform.

Comment: Would it also be possible to generate a shortcut file for Linux on Windows? I hope it would be possible to generate Linux symlinks from Windows shortcuts, and vice versa.

Comment: As well as shortcuts, Windows also has symbolic links, junction points, and hard links.  They tend to stay hidden under the covers, as it were, but they exist.

Comment: Symlinks actually do exist in Windows. See here: http://superuser.com/questions/253935/what-is-the-difference-between-symbolic-link-and-shortcut

Comment: As of Windows Vista you can create symlinks using the 'mklink' command see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: @JamesBarnett One notable issue is that symlinking normally requires admin privileges, so there isn't widespread use. For directory symlinks you have junctions though; it works pretty fine.